# Make netbeans use virtual box guest installation of phpunit

Tags: batch-file, netbeans, cmd, phpunit, virtualbox

We use netbean's phpunit / unit testing plugins for all our testing.  We used to use xampp and point netbeans at our our .bat file from the xampp installation.  We recently started using vagrant and are now running our dev environment in virtual box.  I would like to make netbeans use the installation of phpunit within the virtual machine.  This would save us from having to have both installed.  Is this even possible?  Netbeans seems to want a file location and I am stumped as to how I can go about doing this.

[EDIT] I've created a custom batch file that uses vbox guestconrols to forward the commands to the VMs installation of phpunit.  I am going to then point netbeans at my custom .bat file.  My problem is, now, that guestcontrols doesn't seem to be forwarding --bootstrap.  It seems to be trying to take it and use it, rather than forward it along.  The docs say that all the additional arguments will just be passed on, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Here is what I am using in my my_phpunit.bat :

[my_phpunit.bat]

```
@echo off

if "%VBoxManage%" == "" set VBoxManage=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe

"%VBoxManage%" "--nologo" "guestcontrol" "<my_vm_name>" "execute" "--image" "/usr/bin/php5" "/usr/bin/phpunit" "--verbose" "--username" "<user>" "--password" "<pass>" "--wait-stdout" "--wait-stderr" "CustomNetbeansTestSuite" "<path/to/test/suite>" "--bootstrap" "<path/to/bootstrap>" %7
```

I am almost there, as running the bat file without the bootstrap option at the end takes me to the unit test.  I am getting exceptions because of some autoloader issues(no bootstrap), but if I can figure out a better way to forward these command line arguments to

[EDIT 2]
I think I've finally solved this, but I need to get some issues with my guest OS in order.  Once I've been able to test it a bit more, I'll post the final solution.  I solved the Vbox guest control issue by adding "--" before I actually sent the parameters that should be forwarded.  It said to do so in the docs, but it wasn't entirely clear to me at first.

Comment: There may be a possibility through VBox's shared directories.

Comment: I am having a really difficult time finding it, if there is a way.  Everything I come across seems to address the situation as if it were sharing the host to the guest; not the other way around.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046510/remote-xdebug-with-virtualbox

Comment: @polygone, so did you solve this problem yet?  Still waiting for help?  Can you post an answer or delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update that I never actually got the .bat file to work.  I think I got pretty close, but I was hung up on some linux CLI output that I couldn't suppress. The .bat file that I ended up with was:

```
# .bat example
https://pastebin.com/BX1xnL3q
```

I ended up moving to PhpStorm and everything worked out of the box.  So, if you're still using netbeans, you can try and give that a shot.  Maybe someone with more unix / linux experience can fix the issues I was having. I feel I was like 99% there with it.